# Need to play WAV files in Electron using Vue.js or Javascript, No support for WAV from Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, audio, vue.js, electron

Problem is chrome doesn't support WAV files and Electron is built on Chrome.

Our recording server software (Asterisk) records calls to WAV and have no choice but to use WAV as a format since there are more than 100000 recordings.

Only option it seems for now would be to convert the files to mp3 on the fly when that file is requested but having some difficulty getting there.

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the node packages [wav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav) and [speaker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speaker), they should offer the functionality you desire.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Appreciate it! Cannot wait for Monday morning to see how it goes.